# How to enable observable of from class

Tags: rxjs

I imported from class from rxjs but it is not effective.
So the .from in the sendMosaic method causes an error but I do not know the solution.

What I have so far is the code like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Account, NEMLibrary, NetworkTypes, Address, AccountHttp, AccountOwnedAssetService, AssetHttp, AssetId, TransferTransaction, TimeWindow, EmptyMessage, TransactionHttp } from "nem-library";
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    // Initialize NEMLibrary for TEST_NET Network
    NEMLibrary.bootstrap(NetworkTypes.TEST_NET);
  }


  // Send mosaic
  sendMosaic = () => {
    const privateKey = "";
    const address = this.user.address;
    const amount = 1;
    const account = Account.createWithPrivateKey(privateKey);

    Observable
      .from([{ mosaic: new AssetId(this.admin.mosaic.nameSpace, this.admin.mosaic.name), quantity: amount }])
      .flatMap((_) => new AssetHttp().getAssetTransferableWithAbsoluteAmount(_.mosaic, _.quantity))
      .toArray()
      .map((mosaics) => TransferTransaction.createWithAssets(
        TimeWindow.createWithDeadline(),
        new Address(address),
        mosaics,
        EmptyMessage
      ))
      .map((transaction) => account.signTransaction(transaction))
      .flatMap((signedTransaction) => new TransactionHttp().announceTransaction(signedTransaction))
      .subscribe(
        (value) => {
          console.log("Success:" + value.message);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log("Failed:" + err.toString());
        }
      );
  }
}
```

The error is thrown after compile.

```
"ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(71,8): error TS2339: Property 'from' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'."
```

Comment: Are you using RxJS 5 or RxJS 6? It looks like you are using RxJS 6 style imports, but RxJS 5 in your implementation. I think if you are using RxJS 5 you need to import it like this: `import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';`

Comment: That's not how you use `from` operator. Just do `from()`, not `Observable.from()`. It was changed in RxJs 6.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I'm using RxJS6.